# How to pause a script when it ends on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, command-line

I am running command-line Python scripts from the Windows taskbar by having a shortcut pointing to the Python interpreter with the actual script as a parameter.

After the script has been processed, the interpreter terminates and the output window is closed which makes it impossible to read script output.

What is the most straightforward way to keep the interpreter window open until any key is pressed?

In batch files, one can end the script with pause. The closest thing to this I found in python is `raw_input()` *which is sub-optimal* because it requires pressing the return key (instead of any key).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

One way is to leave a `raw_input()` at the end so the script waits for you to press Enter before it terminates.

Comment: [With Python 3+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/easy-how-to-use-raw-input-in-3-1), this has changed to just `input()`.

Comment: This isn't a solution.  I don't know why the answerer chose it.  The specifications were "Press any key and not just Enter".  This solution works with enter, only.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 While I agree that this answer clearly doesn't answer the question it should be pointed out that this is a high on the list for a google search for "python pause" so it is still useful to have this answer.

Comment: Don't you think it would make sense to answer the actual question, though? If even in a comment?

Answer (score 45):

Try `os.system("pause")` — I used it and it worked for me.

Make sure to include `import os` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 14):

There's no need to wait for input before closing, just change your command like so:

```
cmd /K python <script>
```

The `/K` switch will execute the command that follows, but leave the command interpreter window open, in contrast to `/C`, which executes and then closes.

Comment: This doesn't help in the case specified by Bernd: starting a script from a taskbar shortcut, unless the shortcut is properly configures (which is not the default case).

Comment: @bgbg: but the whole idea is that the shortcut is changed

Comment: /K requires to terminate cmd via "exit" or closing the window using the mouse. That's a bit more than a single keypress :-)

Comment: @Bernd: True, but you can use Alt + Space + C, and it prevents you from having to rewrite all your scripts!

Answer (score 12):

The best option: `os.system('pause')` <-- this will actually display a message saying 'press any key to continue' whereas adding just `raw_input('')` will print no message, just the cursor will be available.

not related to answer:

`os.system("some cmd command")` is a really great command as the command can execute any batch file/cmd commands.

Comment: This answer should be upvoted, this is a real answer to the question.
The one accepted is not the right answer to the question.

Answer (score 7):

> One way is to leave a raw_input() at the end so the script waits for you to press enter before it terminates.

The advantage of using raw_input() instead of msvcrt.* stuff is that the former is a part of standard Python (i.e. absolutely cross-platform). This also means that the script window will be alive after double-clicking on the script file icon, without the need to do

```
cmd /K python <script>
```

Comment: +1: Many people can find the "Enter" or "Return" key without making large mistakes.  Demanding "any key" instead of return seems a bit silly.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows you can use the [`msvcrt`](http://docs.python.org/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt-console) module.

> - [**`msvcrt.kbhit()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit) 
>   Return `True` if a keypress is waiting to be read.
> - [**`msvcrt.getch()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch) 
>   Read a keypress and return the resulting character as a byte string. Nothing is echoed to the console. This call will block if a keypress is not already available, but will not wait for Enter to be pressed. If the pressed key was a special function key, this will return `'\000'` or `'\xe0'`; the next call will return the keycode. The `Control-C` keypress cannot be read with this function.

If you want it to also work on Unix-like systems you can try [this solution](http://pyfaq.infogami.com/how-do-i-get-a-single-keypress-at-a-time) using the [termios](http://docs.python.org/library/termios.html) and [fcntl](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html) modules.

Answer (score 3):

As to the "problem" of what key to press to close it, I (and thousands of others, I'm sure) simply use `input("Press Enter to close")`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple way to do this, you can use keyboard module's `wait` function. For example, you can do:

```
import keyboard
print("things before the pause")
keyboard.wait("esc") # esc is just an example, you can obviously put every key you want
print("things after the pause")
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting python to read a single character from the terminal in an unbuffered manner is a little bit tricky, but here's a recipe that'll do it:

[Recipe 134892: getch()-like unbuffered character reading from stdin on both Windows and Unix (Python)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892-getch-like-unbuffered-character-reading-from-stdin/)

Answer (score 1):

On `Windows 10` insert at beggining this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Strange, but it works for me! (Together with  `input()` at the end, of course)

Answer (score 0):

An external WConio module can help here: http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/wconio.html

```
import WConio
WConio.getch()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pdb
pdb.debug()
```

This is used to debug the script. Should be useful to break also.

Answer (score 0):

If you type

```
input("")
```

It will wait for them to press any button then it will continue. Also you can put text between the quotes.