# raw_input() is deprecated in python 3.1?

Tags: python, raw-input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy: How to use Raw_input in 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/easy-how-to-use-raw-input-in-3-1)

in old style i can entering data with this function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

raw_input is now `input` per http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 3):

`raw_input` has been renamed to `input`. The 2.x `input`, which `eval`'d the input, was removed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `input()` instead, which uses the behavior of `raw_input()` from 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

in Python 3 you use input function