# Get a list of numbers as input from the user

Tags: python, list, input

I tried to use `input` (Py3) /`raw_input()` (Py2) to get a list of numbers, however with the code

```
numbers = input()
print(len(numbers))
```

the input `[1,2,3]` and `1 2 3` gives a result of `7` and `5` respectively – it seems to interpret the input as if it were a string. Is there any direct way to make a list out of it? Maybe I could use `re.findall` to extract the integers, but if possible, I would prefer to use a more Pythonic solution.

Comment: "it seems to interpret the input as if it were a string." No "interpretation" happens (unless you count translating keystrokes into bytes and then bytes into text); the input **is** a string.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In Python 3.x, use this.

```
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

### Example

```
>>> a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
3 4 5
>>> a
[3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Comment: http://introtopython.org/lists_tuples.html#List-Comprehensions
maybe this is helpful.

Comment: Can this accept different data types other than int? i.e. Can I replace `int(x)` with `string(x)`

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Yes although the expression would be str(x) instead of string(x) since str is python's way of saying string

Comment: @DhirajBarnwal If you want to know what's going on there: `input()` to read input + `split()` to split the input on spaces + `[f(x) for x in iter]` to loop over each of those + `int` to turn each into an int. If you want to know how one can come up with it: it's mostly just figuring out what you want to do and which pieces you need to put together to achieve that.

Comment: I would have +1 if you had an extra 2 lines of explanation which @Dukeling did in the comments.

Comment: @Stevoisiak `x` is already a string (`str`), so no need to convert it :)

Answer (score 62):

It is much easier to parse a list of numbers separated by spaces rather than trying to parse Python syntax:

Python 3:

```
s = input()
numbers = list(map(int, s.split()))
```

Python 2:

```
s = raw_input()
numbers = map(int, s.split())
```

Comment: After python 2.7 raw_input() was renamed to input(). Stack overflow [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/954840/318807)

Comment: what if my input is having mixed datatype string and integer then how can i split them and convert to list.
input: 'aaa' 3 45 554 'bbb' 34 'ccc'
i added the contents seperated by space!!

Comment: @FarhanPatel That's an unrelated question, so I suggest asking a new question.  Start with looping over `s.split()` or `shlex.split(s)` if you want to allow spaces inside quoted strings.

Comment: posting it as a new question, thnx for the encouragement, was scary it might not be marked as duplicate!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822895/how-to-separate-a-mixed-datatype-string-taken-as-input-into-list

Answer (score 11):

### Using Python-like syntax

The standard library provides [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), which can evaluate certain strings as though they were Python code. This does not create a security risk, but it *can still result in crashes and a wide variety of exceptions*.

For example: on my machine `ast.literal_eval('['*1000 + ']'*1000)` will raise `MemoryError`, even though the input is only two kilobytes of text.

As explained in the documentation:

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, `None` and `Ellipsis`.

(The documentation is *slightly* inaccurate. `ast.literal_eval` also [supports addition and subtraction of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584417) - but **not** any other operators - so that it can support complex numbers.)

This is sufficient for reading and parsing a list of integers formatted like Python code (e.g. if the input is `[1, 2, 3]`. For example:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(input("Give me a list: "))
Give me a list: [1,2,3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

##### Do not ever use `eval` for input that could possibly ever come, in whole or in part, from outside the program. It is a critical security risk that enables the creator of that input to run arbitrary code.

It **cannot** be properly sandboxed without significant expertise and massive restrictions - at which point it is obviously much easier to just use `ast.literal_eval`. This is increasingly important in our Web-connected world.

In Python 2.x, `raw_input` is equivalent to Python 3.x `input`; 2.x `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`. Python 2.x thus exposed a critical security risk in its built-in, designed-to-be-beginner-friedly functionality, and did so for many years. It also has not been officially supported since Jan 1, 2020. It is approximately as outdated as Windows 7.

**Do not use Python 2.x unless you absolutely have to; if you do, do not use the built-in `input`.**

### Using your own syntax

Of course, it is clearly possible to parse the input according to custom rules. For example, if we want to read a list of integers, one simple format is to expect the integer values separated by whitespace.

To interpret that, we need to:

- [Split the string at the whitespace](/questions/743806/), which will give us a list
- [Convert strings into integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906), and [apply that logic to each string in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410/).

All of those tasks are covered by the common linked duplicates; the resulting code is shown in the top answer here.

### Using other syntaxes

Rather than inventing a format for the input, we could expect input in some other existing, standard format - such as JSON, CSV etc. The standard library includes tools to parse those two. However, it's generally not very user-friendly to expect people to type such input by hand at a prompt. Normally this kind of input will be read from a file instead.

### Verifying input

`ast.literal_eval` will also read and parse many things that *aren't* a list of integers; so subsequent code that *expects* a list of integers will still need to verify the input.

Aside from that, if the input *isn't* formatted as expected, generally some kind of exception will be thrown. Generally you will want to check for this, in order to repeat the prompt. Please see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.split()`

```
numbers = raw_input().split(",")
print len(numbers)
```

This will still give you strings, but it will be a list of strings.

If you need to map them to a type, use list comprehension:

```
numbers = [int(n, 10) for n in raw_input().split(",")]
print len(numbers)
```

If you want to be able to enter in **any** Python type and have it mapped automatically **and** you trust your users **IMPLICITLY** then you can use [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval)

Answer (score 5):

Another way could be to use the for-loop for this one. 
Let's say you want user to input 10 numbers into a list named "memo"

```
memo=[] 
for i in range (10):
    x=int(input("enter no. \n")) 
    memo.insert(i,x)
    i+=1
print(memo)
```

Comment: This takes each number as a separate input, on a separate line. The question implies a single line of input with one call to `input`...

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a string representation of the list to json:

```
import json

str_list = raw_input("Enter in a list: ")
my_list = json.loads(str_list)
```

user enters in the list as you would in python: `[2, 34, 5.6, 90]`

Answer (score 0):

Answer is trivial. try this.

`x=input()`

Suppose that `[1,3,5,'aA','8as']` are given as the inputs

`print len(x)`

this gives an answer of 5

`print x[3]`

this gives `'aA'`

Comment: This is only true in 2.x, and exposes a **critical security risk**.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[]
b=int(input())
for i in range(b):
    c=int(input())
    a.append(c)
```

The above code snippets is easy method to get values from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of number as input from the user.

This can be done by using **list in python.**

```
L=list(map(int,input(),split()))
```

Here **L** indicates list, **map** is used to map input with the position, **int** specifies the datatype of the user input which is in integer datatype, and **split()** is used to split the number based on space.

.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think if you do it without the split() as mentioned in the first answer. It will work for all the values without spaces. So you don't have to give spaces as in the first answer which is more convenient I guess.

```
a = [int(x) for x in input()]
a
```

Here is my ouput:

```
11111
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: What if I want to pass `1, 11, 111`or maybe `11, 1, 111`? In your program they will all just be `1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1`... Bottom line, this only works for ***single digit*** numbers which is pretty restrictive...

Answer (score -1):

try this one ,

```
n=int(raw_input("Enter length of the list"))
l1=[]
for i in range(n):
    a=raw_input()
    if(a.isdigit()):
        l1.insert(i,float(a)) #statement1
    else:
        l1.insert(i,a)        #statement2
```

If the element of the list is just a number the statement 1 will get executed and if it is a string then statement 2 will be executed. In the end you will have an list l1 as you needed.