# How to convert numbers to a number list in python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get a list as input from the user in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/how-can-i-get-a-list-as-input-from-the-user-in-python)

I currently have this:

```
c = eval(input("Enter a group of numbers "))
#say someone types 123
print (c)
#prints out 123
```

I want this:

```
c = eval(input("Enter a group of numbers "))
#say they enter 123
print (c)
#prints out [1,2,3]
```

I want `123` to end up as `[1,2,3]`. How can I do that?

Comment: Do NOT use `eval`. Also, if you're using python 2, don't use `input`. Both will result in an arbitrary code execution vulnerability.

Comment: I know everyone likes easy rep, but for quality Q&A, common questions really need to be closed, not answered with a dozen identical answers every time.

Answer (score 6):

```
In [32]: c=raw_input()
123

In [33]: map(int,c)
Out[33]: [1, 2, 3]
```

use `split()` if the input is something like `1 2 3`:

```
In [37]: c=raw_input()
1 2 3

In [38]: map(int,c.split())
Out[38]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the numbers into `int`s using `map()`:

```
>>> map(int, '123')
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> s = '123'
>>> [int(c) for c in s]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about?:

```
c = [int(x) for x in input("Enter a group of numbers ")]
#list comprehension over the input function
```

Entering 123 the result is [1, 2, 3]

OK, lets say that for python 2.x (input returns an int object)

```
c = [int(x) for x in str(input("Enter a group of numbers "))]
#added an str() function for iterating
```

Comment: this won't work in python 2.x

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: It will. I just tested it with Python 2.6.

Comment: I'm happy it is usefull for you.

Comment: @Blender No it won't, `input()` will return an integer in python 2.x, and the for loop will raise the error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: My bad, I tested something a little bit different.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary, You could just add an str() for the input, so it will work in python 2.x

Comment: @user1717888 I wonder how this solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a string, and then convert each character in the string into a number.

```
myStr = str(myInt)
out = [int(i) for i in myStr]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the following:

```
c = eval(input("Enter a group of numbers "))
```

Is the same as:

```
c = eval(eval(raw_input("Enter a group of numbers ")))
```

So you are calling eval twice now. More information on [input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input).

This is a possible solution for what you want:

```
c = raw_input("Enter a group of numbers "))
c = [int(i) for i in c]
print(c)
```

You can of course reduce the above example to two lines (even one actually).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use [eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) on user input generally. Someone can type a statement that will eval into mischief.

For the same reason, you should avoid the use of [input()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) since it is the equivalent of `eval(raw_input())` also can lead to mischief -- intended or not.

You can, however, SAFELY get Python interpretation of user input into Python data structures with [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(raw_input('Type Python input: '))
Type Python input: 1,2,3
(1, 2, 3)
>>> ast.literal_eval(raw_input('Type Python input: '))
Type Python input: [1,2,3]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> ast.literal_eval(raw_input('Type Python input: '))
Type Python input: 123
123
>>> ast.literal_eval(raw_input('type a number: '))
type a number: 0xab
171
```

(In each case, the first line after `>>> Type Python input:` is what I typed into the `raw_input()`

If you want to split digits apart, you can do this:

```
>>> [int(c) for c in raw_input() if c in '1234567890']
1234
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [int(c) for c in raw_input() if c in '1234567890']
123a45
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Notice the non digit is filtered.