# Multiplying each element in the list by 2

Tags: python, list

The question is Write a function called double_it()  should iterate through the list and multiply each numeric element in the original list by 2 and reuturn integer representing the number of elements that were doubled.

Here is what I have..... the output is just repeating the list 2 times but not multiplying the values.

```
def main():
    original_list = [input("Enter a list of numbers: ")]
    double_it(original_list)

def double_it(new_list):
    for index in range(len(new_list)):
        new_list[index] *= 2
        print new_list

main()
```

Comment: You've created a list with one element which is the input. Take the [] out around input.

Comment: if the list is numeric, the number of the doubled numbers is its len. `len(new_list)`

Answer (score 4):

Your problem looks like an error with handling the input. The raw_input function should generally be preferred over input.

I'll defer to this Stack Overflow question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/how-can-i-get-a-list-as-input-from-the-user-in-python

As for the doubling part, there are a few ways to do this that might be worth knowing about, to fully explore python.

### Iterative

```
>>> originalList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> newList = []
>>> for item in originalList:
...     newList.append(item*2)
... 
>>> print(newList)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

### List Comprehensions

```
>>> originalList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> newList = [item*2 for item in originalList]
>>> print(newList)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

### Maps

```
>>> def double(x): return 2*x
... 
>>> originalList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> newList = list(map(double, originalList))
>>> print(newList)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

The python docs around this stuff are all quite good, and an excellent learning resource.

Answer (score 2):

Your `double_it()` method works fine, just modify this line

```
original_list = [input("Enter a list of numbers: ")]
```

to

```
original_list = input("Enter a list of numbers: ")
```

**Why?** Because`input()` will evaluate the list you enter as a `list`, so you can work with it as a list, try printint the **type**:

```
a = input("Enter a list of numbers: ")
print type(a)

Enter a list of numbers: [1,2,3]
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: then where do i put the [] around so python knows the input is a list?

Comment: In 2.x, input() evaluates the input as a python 2.x expression.  In 3.x, that is no longer true.  That's because 2.x's input() is a bit of a security problem.  IMO, It's better to use sys.stdin.readline() and convert.