# Asking for a list of numbers from the user

Tags: python

I would need to work with a list of numbers given from the user, but I think if I ask a user to give me a list, he would't be able to put the brackets []. So if I write :

```
input('Please enter a list of numbers ')
```

he won't be able to do it so simply. And I also want to ask the user how many times numbers should I put in that list.  But how can ask the user to input me say n numbers so that I can use that  in a list.

Comment: ask the user to supply a list or dict

Comment: checkout - > http://stackoverflow.com/a/4663342/5272003

Comment: Briefly: `numbers = [int(x) for x in input('Please enter your numbers, separated by a space: ').split()]` for Python 3. For Python 2, replace `input` with `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

Ask for numbers separated with spaces then use this:

```
my_list = [int(x) for x in input('Please enter a list of numbers ').split()]
```