# Get the list length and its elements as the input

Tags: python, list

I want to get list length and the corresponding elements as the input.

```
      int(input("Please enter how long the list is: "))
      my_list = [56,3,89,2,34,12]
   def my_sort(l) :
my_sorted = False
sorted_pos= len(l)-1


print(l)
while not sorted_list:
   sorted_list= True 
   for index in range(sorted_pos):
       if my_list[index] > my_list[index +1]:
           sorted_list= False
           my_list[index], my_list[index +1] = my_list[index +1], my_list[index]
           print(l)
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: You can see [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user).

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted this:

```
elems   = int(input("Please enter how long the list is: "))
my_list = []

for i in range(elems):
    elem = int(input("Please enter next element: "))
    my_list.append(elem)

def my_sort(l):
    sorted_list = False
    sorted_pos= len(l)-1

    print(l)

    while not sorted_list:
       sorted_list = True 
       for index in range(sorted_pos):
           if l[index] > l[index +1]:
               sorted_list = False
               l[index], l[index +1] = l[index +1], l[index]
    print(l)

my_sort(my_list)
```

Note that the indentation in Python is important.

In the first statement you get the number of items from the user and save it in the variable `elems`.

Then in the `for` loop you ask the user put individual elements and append it to (originally empty) list `my_list`.

In the next step you create (define) the function `my_sort` which takes as argument a list of numbers. You named this argument as `l`. This function print the given list, sort it end finally print sorted list.

Your last step is to call this function with your list `my_list` instead of formal argument `l`.