# How take *args input from user in a function

Tags: python, args

How take *args input from user in a function in Python.
I want to take input from user and get the addition user given input.

```
def add(*args):
    s = 0
    for i in args:
        s+=i
    print(s)
```

Output will be: 180

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user. Can't VTC, since I already VTC'd for a different reason initially.

Comment: Why will the output be 180? Won't the output depend on the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command line arguments are inserted by the interpreter in `argv` list which is a global variable in `sys` module. So you just need to import it.

Note however that `argv[0]` is the actual name of the running script and so the real arguments start from `argv[1]`. Also, those arguments are treated as strings even if they are numbers. So we need to convert them to `ints` (Here, I am assuming your addition function is supposed to be adding integers. If not, edit accordingly or write me a comment).

The code for the above, if we were to use your function without any changes, would be the following:

```
from sys import argv
args = [int(x) for x in argv[1:]]
add(args) # your function call
```

---

If we were to also change your function, a simpler code (self-contained inside your function) would be the following:

```
from sys import argv

def add_args():
    s = 0
    for i in argv[1:]:
        s += int(i)

    print(s)
```

Comment: Instead of `list(map(lambda x: int(x), argv[1:]))` it would be a bit clearer (more Pythonic) to use a list comprehension: `[int(x) for x in argv[1:]]`

Comment: Or indeed not to define a lambda which just calls another function! i.e. `list(map(int, argv[1:]))`. But I still think the list comprehension is clearer still (but your final suggestion is clearest of all; but I would move the import out of the function to the top of the file).

Comment: @ArthurTacca Indeed, `map` and  `lambda` completely unnecessary. I am about to edit that. Yes, I suppose you could also argue that importing in the beginning is better, although in some cases I greatly prefer it just before usage. In that case, I placed inside so that the code is truly self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def add(*args):
    s = 0
    for i in args:
        s+=i
    print(s)

add(*list(map(int,input("Enter the numbers").split())))
```

Comment: Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than the existing answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)