# Print an array in the range of a user input

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop

Below is my code:

```
 n = int(input())

 for i in range(n):

    d = int(input())

    for i in range(d):
        a = list(map(int,input().split()))
    print(a)
```

But I want my code to do this, for example:
Suppose `d = 4` is my user input
Now, I want (random example) `a = [1, 4 , 8, 19]`. That too from user input.
This is an example of the output of. I am not able to frame the question properly. So, here is the  desired output:

3 #input for n

2 #input for d

[4,6] #output for a

5 #input for 2nd d

[4,2,1,4,7] #output for a, 5 elements as d = 5

2 #input for last d, as 'n' was 3

[1,9] #(the last array a)

Comment: Your code is already getting a list as user input and storing it in `a`. What's the problem?

Comment: Sir, can I show an example of an output of what I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Comment: Can you now get my question? Please check the desired output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified. It seems like you are trying to combine the 2 very different methods of collecting data below. You should choose one or the other.

**Individual entries**

```
n = int(input('How many numbers?\n'))

res = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
    res.append(int(input('Enter number{0}\n'.format(i))))
```

**Simultaneous entries**

```
n = int(input('How many numbers?\n'))

in_str = input('Enter the numbers separated by space:\n')

res = list(map(int, in_str.split()))
```

Comment: Please **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49656317/edit)** your question, do not put code in comments.

Comment: Sorry, I just did that. please check it out.

Comment: @GunjanPatait, nope still not clear how you got all those numbers.

Comment: There need to be two for loops and the array must be simultaneous. The first loop runs for "n" and inside it, the second for loop runs for "d".Help me out, please.

Comment: And what's your desired output? Update your question, please.

Comment: Can you get my desired output now? sir!

Answer (score 0):

### Problems with your code

- you are using same `i` variable in both for loop
- `a = list(map(int,input().split()))` scans whole line, so no need of for loop

### Solution

```py
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):

    d = int(input())

    a = list(map(int,input().split()))
    print(a)
```

### Output

```sh
2
5
1 2 3 4 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # Output
2   
1 2
[1, 2]  # output
```

If you got your answer please accept it else comment What's the problem?