# Why won't Python store 0 in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code that takes an input number, multiplies the first digit by 3 and then prints out the first digit. When I input 023, it gives me 6 instead of 0. Why is that?

```
a=int(input())

b=str(a)

c=int(b[0])*3

print(c)
```

Comment: You're converting the input string to int, so the leading zero is removed.

Comment: How should I make it not remove the 0?

Comment: I guess by not converting it into an int: `a = input()`

Comment: How can I do it if I want to restrict the input to int?

Comment: Why don't you make the user enter a list of integers? For doing that, I suggest you to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user).

Comment: Loop around the `input()` to validate the input is an `int` before proceeding, but don't convert the input to `int` unless you need to.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing:

```
a=int(input())

So if input() = '023', int('023') will be 23. So a=23

b=str(a) => b='23'

int(b[0]) => c=2*3=6
```

You should do:

```
 a=input()
```

then

```
c=int(a[0])*3
```

Comment: This works but it also allows suspicious inputs to go through, such as `3foo`, which might be valid or not depending on the OP's use cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep all the digits you're entering you shouldn't convert your input into an `int`:

```
a=input('Enter a number: ') 
c=int(a[0])*3 
print(c)
```

If you enter `023` this returns `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop to keep asking the user for digit-only input until the user enters one, and you should use the `list()` constructor to convert the digits to a list:

```
while True:
    a = input('Enter digits: ')
    if a.isdigit():
        break
    print('Please enter only digits.')
b=list(a)
c=int(b[0])*3
print(c)
```