# Fix EOF error when taking list as input and checking if sorted?

Tags: python-3.3

Here is my code:

```
lstInput = input('Type here: ')
lst = list(lstInput)
def is_sorted(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        for x in range(len(lst)):
            if lst[x] > lst[x+1]:
                return False
    return True
is_sorted(lst)
```

When I try to run it in zybooks, my class textbook, I get an EOF error for lstinput = input("Type here: ").  I do not get an error in IDLE. Please help.  Thanks

Comment: This question is probably too localized, but can you share a link to that notebook?

Comment: By the way, `lst` is going to be a string and not a list as you expect it to be.

Comment: Related: [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)