# numbers into symbols (Python)

Tags: python

I have a problem with the task, I need to input numbers and print it like a histogram with symbol ($). One unit is one ($) symbol.

For example:

```
input

1 5 3 2

print

$
$$$$$
$$$
$$
```

The code at the moment:

```
number = int(input())
while (number > 0):
    print('$' * number)
    number = 0
```

This works only with one number.

What need to do to code work properly?

Comment: You need to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string `"1 5 3 2"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 1):

You're close and your thinking is right.

When you input() a string a numbers separated by a space, you need to convert each number into an integer, because by default all arguments are string for input.

You can use the map function to convert each input to integer.

```
inp = map(int, input().split())
```

Here `input().split()` converts `1 5 3 2` to `['1', '5', '3', '2']`

Then applying map(int, [1, 5, 3, 2]) is equivalent to doing int(1), int(5) to each element.

Syntax of map: `map(function, Iterable)` function is `int()` in out case.

Then as you have the integers, all you need to do is take each value and print the number of '$'

```
for val in inp:
    print('$'*val)
```

Here's the complete code:

```
inp = map(int, input().split())
for val in inp:
    print('$'*val)

$
$$$$$
$$$
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like the follwoing,

```
>>> x = input("Enter the numbers: ") # use `raw_input` if `python2`
Enter the numbers: 1 2 3 4 5
>>> x
'1 2 3 4 5'
>>> y = [int(z) for z in x.split()]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i in y:
...   print('$' * i)
... 
$
$$
$$$
$$$$
$$$$$
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = raw_input("input :")
for number in [li for li in numbers.split(" ") if li.isdigit()]:
    print('$' * int(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
#get numbers as string
numbers = input('Enter numbers separated by <space> :')
# split numbers (create list)
nums = numbers.split(' ')
#loop each number
for num in nums:
    print_num = ''
    #create what to print
    for i in range(int(num)):
        print_num = print_num + '$'
    #print
    print(print_num)
```