# How to sort a list with space between them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to sort a list with space 
like,

```
my_list = [20 10 50 400 100 500]
```

but I got an error

> ```
> "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10 20 50 100 500 400 '"
> ```

code:

```
strength = int(input())
strength_s = strength.sort()
print(strength_s)
```

Comment: try changing your first line to `strength = map(int, input().split())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 1):

The `input` function in `python` returns the entire line as a `str`.
So, if you enter a space separated list of ints, the `input` function will return the entire line as a string.

```py
>>> a = input()
1 2 3 4 5

>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>

>>> a
'1 2 3 4 5'
```

If you want to save this as a list of integers, you have to follow the following procedure.

```py
>>> a = input()
1 2 3 4 5
>>> a
'1 2 3 4 5'
```

Now, we need to separate the numbers in the string, i.e. split the string.

```py
>>> a = a.strip().split()  # .strip() will simply get rid of trailing whitespaces
>>> a
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

We now have a `list` of `strings`, we have to convert it to a `list` of `ints`. We have to call `int()` for each element of the `list`, and the best way to do this is using the `map` function.

```py
>>> a = map(int, a)
>>> a
<map object at 0x0081B510>
>>> a = list(a)  # map() returns a map object which is a generator, it has to be converted to a list
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

We finally have a `list` of `ints`

**This entire process is mostly done in one line of `python` code:**

```py
>>> a = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
1 2 3 4 5 6
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get inputs with space from the user:

```
strength = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
```

Sort them:

```
strength.sort()
```

And print:

```
print(strength)
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, `my_list = [20 10 50 400 100 500]` is neither a list, nor the correct way to represent one.
You represent a list using `my_list = [20, 10 ,50, 400, 100, 500]` .
I will assume `my_list` is a string. So then you will split the string into a list, convert the list to an integer and then sort it, like so

```
my_list = "20 10 50 400 100 500"
li = [int(item) for item in my_list.split(' ')]
print(sorted(li))
#[10, 20, 50, 100, 400, 500]
```

To make your original code work, we would do

```
strength = input()
strength_li = [int(item) for item in strength.split(' ')]
print(sorted(strength_li))
```

And the output will look like.

```
10 20 40 30 60
#[10, 20, 30, 40, 60]
```