# Error "invalid literal for int()" when trying to convert list of numbers from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing this assignment:

> A new fighting game has become popular. There are N number of villains
>   with each having some strength. There are N players in the game with
>   each having some energy. The energy is used to kill the villains. The
>   villain can be killed only if the energy of the player is greater than
>   the strength of the villain.
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 1
> 6
> 112 243 512 343 90 478
> 500 789 234 400 452 150
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> WIN
> ```

This is my code:

```
def main():
    T = int(input(''))
    for i in range(T):
        N = int(input(''))
        strength = []
        energy = []
        for i in range(N):
            strength.append(int(input()))
        for i in range(N):
            energy.append(int(input()))
        strength.sort()
        energy.sort()
        for j in range(len(energy)):
            if strength[i] < energy[i]:
                continue
            else:
                return print('LOSE')
        return print('WIN')

main()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CandidateCode.py", line 23, in 
    main()
  File "CandidateCode.py", line 11, in main
    strength.append(int(input('')))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '112 243 512 343 90 478 '
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should post the code here instead of pictures of it.

Comment: Anyway the error is self explanator. You are trying to convert the string `112 243 512 343 90 478` to an `int`.

Comment: we can't perform that ? then how to take integer input

Comment: In an interactive Python console try running `int('3')`.  What does this do?  Next try running `int('1 2 3')`.  What happens?  Check the [documentation for int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 0):

You can input each number one by one and cast each to `int`. If you want to input all numbers at once you can do this:

```
in = input()
numbers = list(map(int, in.split(' ')))
```

The `map` function apply `int()` to each element of the list which is obtained by splitting the input with the whitespace character. Then you have to convert the result to a `list` as in python-3 the `map` function returns an iterator.