# Python - Input a list and store as list not string

Tags: python

How might I be able to input `[1,2,3]` into python and store it as a list and not as a string (i.e.`'[1,2,3]'`).  `input()` returns a string so does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: One way might be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Thanks for the tip. However, the input is still a set of integers and not a list.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to evaluate the string as a Python expression.  But don't use `eval`, which is unsafe.  Instead use `literal_eval` from `ast`:

```
import ast
r = ast.literal_eval("[1, 2, 3]")
```

This gives `r` the value `[1, 2, 3]`.