# Attempting to unpack a non-sequencepylint(unpacking-non-sequence)

Tags: python

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong in this code:

```
def greater(a,b):
    if a > b:
        return a
    return b

num1, num2 = int(input("enter two number : ").split(","))
print(f"bigger is :  {greater(num1,num2)}")


TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: `split()` returns a list. You are passing that list to `int()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 1):

You have

- `input("enter two number : ")` that values let's say `1,2`
- `input("...").split(",")` is now `['1', '2']` so a `list` of 2 string
- `int(['1', '2'])` << you can't do that

---

You need to `map` each value to `int`

```
num1, num2 = map(int,input("enter two number : ").split(","))
```

Or do

```
values = input("enter two number : ").split(",")
num1, num2 = int(values[0]), int(values[1])
```

Comment: @DavidBuck oh thanks, didn't even try I thought i already get an error of unpacking from map, thanks

Comment: There is a `)` missing after first `int` function in second line of second method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following one liner:

```
print("Bigger is", max([int(x) for x in input("Enter 2 numbers separated by comma: ").split(",")]))
```

No need for your `greater` function.

Understanding above code yourself may be educative.