# Taking single value input in Python

Tags: python

I was attempting to do one kata problem in Python, where I have two lists of input, let's say weight and value, which was getting input in the order (value1, weight1, value2, weight2,....)
If it were C++, I could just take one element at a time with `cin` to my arrays. But with Python I don't know how to take this input.
If the input is like

`60 10 100 20 120 30` (in a single line)

I want my two lists val and w have values

```
val=[60,100,120]
w=[10,20,30]
```

How to take this kind of inputs in Python? Is it possible to read only one input at a time, like cin does in C++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user). Your title is really misleading. You ask about the complete opposite...

Comment: @Tomerikoo No, I knew how to take whole list as an input, my question was if we can get single element like cin in C++ does? or in some way where we can directly assign lists to the input without taking extra list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read space-separated input to a list using `split`and then use slicing to get the odd/even indexed elements:

```
val = input().split()
val = [int(i) for i in val] #to integer
w = val[1::2] # get only odd indices
val = val[0::2] # get only even indices

print(val) # [60,100,120]
print(w) # [10,20,30]
```

You can then use regular indexing to get individual elements in the lists.

Comment: right, this will require one extra list to take input and then we can split it to 2 other arrays based on indexing. This will surely work, just wondering if we have a better way

Comment: If you have 2 rows of input, you could do `val = input().split()` `w = input().split()`, `val, w = [int(i) for i in val], [int(i) for i in w]`.

Comment: Read the question. The values are interwined in one line

Comment: Updated, this should be the simplest method (using slicing)

Comment: This is a good way. You might just put the int conversion and input in one line: `val = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
values = input("Enter values: ").split(" ")

if(len(values) % 2 != 0):
    print("Error, uneven number of values and weights")
else:
    val = []
    w = []
    for i in range(0, len(values) - 1, 2):
        val.append(values[i])
        w.append(values[i+1])

    print("val: ", val)
    print("w: ", w)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution:

```py
a = "60 10 100 20 120 30"
split_a = a.split(" ")
val = [e for (i, e) in enumerate(split_a) if i % 2 == 0]
w = [e for (i, e) in enumerate(split_a) if i % 2 == 1]
# or shorter with slicing (start:stop:step)
val = [e for e in split_a[0::2]]
w = [e for e in split_a[1::2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot as far as I know. `input()` is a function that reads one line at a time as an entire string.
A popular way to make a list out of an entire line of space separated integers is using the in-built `map()` function and `split()` method of a string object:

```
numbers = map(int, input.split())
```

`numbers` will now contain the list of numbers on that line.
Firstly, `input()` reads the entire line as a string including spaces.
`split()` function splits the input at space, you can also pass in a string argument to make it split anywhere you want, i.e a custom delimiter like `,` and creates a list of strings of those numbers 
`map()` calls `int()` on each of the numbers in that list.
In C++, just like you need to know the size of input in advance, you can run a for loop on the list to now split values and weights into two lists.

```
val, w = [], []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    if i % 2 == 0: val.append(numbers[i])
    else: w.append(numbers[i])
```

For better performance(relevant for large input size),  you can even skip the `map()` step, and do something like this:

```
numbers = input().split()
val, w = [], []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    if i % 2 == 0: val.append(int(numbers[i]))
    else: w.append(int(numbers[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `cin` does but I assume the input you have is a string. One way you could do is to split it into a list of ints. And then create your val and w lists and append your values into the lists. (The first, third, fifth, etc would be your val list)

```
my_input_list = my_input.split(' ')
```

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp).