# Making a function that can check if a specific digit in a number string is present

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a function that can see if an input contains an int in some way.

For example, if the input was 17, 7, 70, 87 etc. It could check if a seven is present. Like the number 17 contains a 7.

Code:

```
UserInput = int(input("Input a number and check if it contains 7"))
if (insert statement to check for 7):
    print("there is a seven in your number")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What obstacle did you encounter during your attempt?

Comment: To better help you, please post your code so far.

Comment: I have not really encountered any obstacles, since I don't know where to begin. Thank you for your help

Comment: I wil just create a quick code then

Comment: `'7' in input()`

Comment: Lookup list comprehension and string.split()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP asked for a function, it would look something like this:

```
def checkNum(num):
    if "7" in str(num):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The `(num)` variable is the information that is passed into the function. In this case, it's your given number. The if statement does pretty much what it says it does. It checks if "7" is in the data that you inputted. If it is, it returns the value of True. If that isn't true, it returns False.

Finally you'll need a statement to print the result of the function and to input your data like this:

```
print(checkNum(*your number here*))
```

You can use `input` instead of a number to type in the number if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Here's a funny way of doing it

```
if len(input("Input a number and check if it contains 7").split('7'))>1:
print("there is a seven in your number")
```

Comment: Well this also works fine! Thank you.