# Python user's numpy input

Tags: python

May my question is really simple, but I can't solve this. So I have my code where I have to user's input x and y. My method doesn't work

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

x=np.array(input('Elements = ')
y=np.array(input('Elements = ')
h=signal.convolve(x,y)
print(h)
```

Comment: For one, you're missing closing parentheses on your input lines. And, you're not converting the input string into anything. If you need a user to enter multiple integers (or floats, you didn't specify), then you have to write code to handle that, not just try to throw the string into a numpy array. Without knowing what you want the users to input or what you want the format to be, it's impossible to help you here. Please specify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `eval`, EG:

```py
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

x=np.array(eval(input('Elements = ')))
y=np.array(eval(input('Elements = ')))
h=signal.convolve(x,y)
print(h)
```

Terminal output:

```
Elements = [1,2,3]
Elements = [4,5]
[ 4 13 22 15]
```

This approach is nice and simple, but be aware that using `eval` on user input can be dangerous (see EG [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)), so if you're going to use this approach, then make sure you trust whoever is going to use your program.

Comment: That's a very bad idea and advice to use `eval`, also it enforces the user to input the data in a Python like manner (`[...]`)

Comment: TBF I did qualify it with a warning about dangers of using `eval`. I don't think `eval` is *always* a bad idea, it depends on the context, IE if you don't know who will be using your program. If you can trust your users, then this approach has the advantage that a) it's nice and simple, and b) it is easy to input multi-dimensional arrays like this (EG `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`) without having to change the source code

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension can be used to achieve this

```py
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
x=np.array([float(value) for value in input('Elements = ').split(',')])
y=np.array([float(value) for value in input('Elements = ').split(',')])
h=signal.convolve(x,y)
print(h)
```

**output:**

```py
Elements = 1, 2, 4
Elements = 3, 4,5
[ 3. 10. 25. 26. 20.]
```