# How to input list filled with int and strings

Tags: python

Is it possible to ask the user to write a list as an input such as [1,2,'a','2'] with different data types without the use of any libraries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` but you should understand the caveats. What if the user types in `os.system("rm -rf .")`?

In Python 2, `input` worked like this (and the "sane" input function was called `raw_input`).

Answer (score 0):

```
user = []
c = int(0)
while True:  
    userindent = user.append(input("Type"))
    c = c + 1 
    if c == 3:
        break
print(user)
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's inbuilt `ast` library's `literal_eval` to accept python data types as a string and convert them

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> user_input = input()
[1,2,'a','2']
>>> user_list = literal_eval(user_input)
>>> user_list
[1, 2, 'a', '2']
```

OR a simpler version would be

```
from ast import literal_eval
user_list = literal_eval(input())
```