# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 89 4 10'

Tags: python

When i run the code in pycharm or some other compiler its is working fine but when i run code in hacker rank and hacker earth  i am getting value error.

Please help me guys. The question is:

**Max Pair Sum**
Given a list of distinct integers A, find the largest sum of any pair of elements.
*Input*

```
6 
1 2 3 89 4 10
```

- First line contains the size of list N.
- Second line contains list elements.

Output

```
99
```

Here it's my solution :

```
N=int(input("enter N :"))
Data=[]
for i in range(N):
    Data.append(int(input()))
#print(Data)
Data.sort()
#print(Data)
max_val=max(Data)
print(max_val)
Data=Data[0:len(Data)-1]
#print(Data)
x=list(map(lambda x:x+max_val,Data))
max_val=max(x)
print(max_val)
```

Comment: *Second line contains list elements.* - you're trying to read N many lines though... seems you're probably supposed to just read the second line, then split it up...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 1):

**input()** in python3 reads the whole line as a string.
In your case, it is reading all numbers at once as string. Now, string contains numbers with spaces that's why python is not able to convert that string to int.

Use, `Data = list(map(int, input().split()))` to read the whole line as an array or a list of integers.

Comment: Or use a list comprehension: `[int(x) for x in input().split()]`

Answer (score 0):

the second line contains multiple values at the same which are separated by " ". so we can take the input from the user which is a string eg "1 2 3 4". we can split the input based on " ", which returns ["1", "2", "3", "4"]. now we are converting this iterable into int by using map which takes int function and iterable from split and converts it to an array [1,2,3,4]

```
N=int(input("enter N :"))
Data=map(int, input().split(" "))  #map returns a list    
#print(Data)
Data.sort()
#print(Data)
max_val=max(Data)
print(max_val)
Data=Data[0:len(Data)-1]
#print(Data)
x=list(map(lambda x:x+max_val,Data))
max_val=max(x)
print(max_val)
```

Comment: [*map(int, input().split(" "))] this is supported in python3.

Comment: how can i scan only 5 elements using split() method ?  i have to give size N here

Comment: [*map(int, input().split(" "))][:N]  or list(map(int, input().split()))[:N]  as the result is a list we can do slicing

Comment: @MuthyalaNagaraju you don't really need `N` in Python. It is relevant for languages like C where you have to declare the list's size. Python lists are dynamic