# Find lost number in number sequence

Tags: python

Okay so basically all i have to do is find a lost number in sequence.

For the input data:

```
5
2 3 1 5
```

The correct answer is

```
4
```

```
def findMissing(n):
    
    tempList = []
    for i in range(0, n-1):
        tempList.append(str(input()))
    return [x for x in range(tempList[0], tempList[-1]+1) if x not in tempList] 
    

findMissing(5)
```

Output:

```
---> 11     return [x for x in range(tempList[0], tempList[-1]+1) if x not in tempList]

TypeError: must be str, not int
```

I've tried something like that, i wanted to create a list, and input would be appearing into that list, then i will return the missing value from that list, but it's not working.

Comment: `range` takes ints, not strs

Comment: `input()` already gives you a `str` -- you want to convert it to an `int`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Comment: Thanks @Samwise it solved my problem, and also my code is working!

Comment: sum(1...n) = n*(n+1)/2. So just sum the numbers you get from input and subtract from sum(1...n)

Comment: For the one-line solution: `print((set(range(1, int(input())+1)) - set(map(int, input().split()))).pop())`

Comment: @Samwise and time complexity for this one is still O(n)?

Comment: yup, there's nothing in there that would result in every element of one set being compared against all the others or anything like that

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a `set` of the "full" sequence using `range` then take the `set.difference` with your given list of data, then that should contain the missing item.

```
def findMissing(n, data):
    return set(range(1, n+1)).difference(data).pop()

>>> findMissing(5, [2, 3, 1, 5])
4
```

Since you know the sequence is contiguous, you can also do this arthimetically

```
def findMissing(n, data):
    return sum(range(1,n+1)) - sum(data)

>>> findMissing(5, [2, 3, 1, 5])
4
```

Comment: And also i have one question, what is time complexity of this one?

Comment: @Daro1234451 The long pole in the tent is likely `set.difference` which based on typical implementation is `O(n)`

Comment: I have also different question, what will be the O(1) solution?

Comment: @Daro1234451 There is no `O(1)` solution

Comment: I don't know exactly why, I thought O(n) will be in the case i will use for loop or i will iterate over something, but even there? I also thought operations set and pop, works in O(1) complexity. Would you mind to explain?

Comment: Okay i understand. Nevermind. Thanks for every help.

Comment: hey is there a solution without using any python tools? Like arithmetic progression sum or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

This error actually comes from this step:

```py
tempList[-1]+1
```

The way to reproduce this would be:

```py
'1' + 1
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

You need to add like types. You can fix it by doing `int(input())` which will convert the string type to an int.

`range` will also throw an error on `str` arguments:

```py
range('1', '3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

So make sure you are giving it integer arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant of @Cory Kramer answer using `set symmetric difference`:

```
def find_missing(number, data):
    return (set(data) ^ set(range(1, number + 1))).pop()

find_missing(5, [2, 3, 1, 5])

>> 4
```

Check the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) for more informations.