# Python beginner : How to take list as an input (not creating a list)

Tags: python, list

I want to write this exact line -
["int", "float", "str"]
in my input ( [] brackets included )and want python to recognize it as a list? is it possible? if not what should I do to make it possible.. I cant enter elements one by one. please help
I am very beginner so plz help

Comment: Hello. Please, could you share the code of what you have tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this. But the simplest is to use the **json** package

```
import json

var = input("Enter list input here: ")

var_list = json.loads(var)

for i in var_list:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in python named 'eval'. If you do something like this

```
input_list = eval(input("Type here: "))
print(type(input_list))
print(input_list)
```

You will get the output

```
Type here: ["int", "float", "str"]
<class 'list'>
['int', 'float', 'str']
```

Comment: This is a VERY DANGEROUS way to do it, as it allows any user to execute any code. eval() should almost never be used with user input strings. The proper way to do it is to use the json.loads() method, as @collinsuz said.

Comment: Agree. If the other users are going to work with the input, don't use eval(). However, in case you use it on your own for development, there is no problem I think.