# Make a user enter an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to coding and I need to plot an array but I could not modify my code to ask the user to enter the array.

passengersByQueue = [5,4,6,1,7,7]

I need to make the user to input 6 numbers instead of the numbers in the code

Comment: Add a plain python tag please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 2):

You could use input() with a loop:

```python
arr = []
count = 6
while count > 0:
  arr.append(input('Enter a number: '))
  count = count - 1
```

or use split():

```python
userInput = input('Enter a comma-separated list of numbers')
arr = userInput.split(',')
```

Edit to add parsing of integers:

The returned array is an array of strings, so you need to convert them back to integers:

```python
newArr = list(map(int, arr))
```

map(int, arr) returns an iterator of the array after the function int() is applied to all members of the array, you have to use list() in order for it to return an actual array. Alternatively, if you use the loop to have the user enter each value one by one, you can use int() before appending to the array.

Comment: Better. Still not integers though

Comment: @MadPhysicist "That's not python" - I don't agree, the code the author posted first is valid Python code, what else ?

Comment: @Programmer. The code was edited to correct what I meant. Comment deleted

Comment: @MadPhysicist Added integer parsing, thanks for letting me know

Comment: You missed a parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use pythons [inbuilt function input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), then you can set a loop like this to read your input list

```
    li = []
    for i in range(n):
      x = input() #get input 
      li.append(int(x)) # append to list
```