# Python remove the trailing white space when inputting a string of numbers

Tags: python-3.x, set, whitespace, removing-whitespace

**I'm looking for a solution to removing the trailing white space when inputting a string of numbers**.

##### Code

```
vals_inp=input()
print('vals_inp',vals_inp)

vals_strip = vals_inp.rstrip()
print('vals_strip', vals_strip, type(vals_inp))

in_set=set(vals_strip) # problem happens here
```

##### OUTPUT

in_set {'1', '2', '3', ' '} #PROBLEM ' '

##### Things tried

I have tried rstrip lstrip rstrip and strip(' ')
I see lots of answers using rstrip etc but its not working for me

#### Why it matters

The ' ' in my set is messing up the subsequent code.  All help appreciated

Comment: If your input is ``1 2 3`` then the ``' '`` is the *separator* of your numbers. A [mre] showing the actual input, or at least the output *corresponding to the script*, would help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```py
vals_inp=input()
print('vals_inp',vals_inp)

vals_strip = vals_inp.rstrip()
print('vals_strip', vals_strip, type(vals))

in_set=set(vals_strip) # problem happens here
```

Comment: vals_strip = vals.rstrip()   --->  vals_strip = vals_inp.rstrip()

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see the correction. but it hasnt solved it.  Now I have: vals_inp=input() 
vals_strip = vals_inp.rstrip() 
in_set=set(vals_strip) 
print('in_set', in_set, type(in_set)) but output is still: in_set {'1', '2', '3', ' '} - ie ' ' is still there

Comment: vals = [x for x in vals_inp if x != '']

Comment: Thank you !!! - rearranging the order I got it to work: vals_inp=input()
list_set = list(vals_inp) vals = [x for x in list_set if x != ' '] set_vals = set(vals) OUTPUT: {'1', '3', '2'}

Comment: This answer seems to provide the same code as the question. How does it fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Awais Khan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69695958/14048071):

```py
vals_inp=input() 
list_set = list(vals_inp) 
vals = [x for x in list_set if x != ' '] 
set_vals = set(vals)
```

```py
OUTPUT: {'1', '3', '2'}\
```

Comment: Note that this is needlessly creating two lists, one of which is rather inefficient; you could just use ``set_vals = set(vals_inp.replace(' ', '')`` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the shorter solution, for me, I still need the steps so it's clear what is happening