# Python is there a quick way to let the user enter a list?

Tags: python

What I usally do when letting the user enter a list is

```
myList = []
for i in range(n): #n is a initalized number
    myList.append(int(input()))
```

This way when the user enters they have to enter 1 item at a time, and need to press enter before they can input the next time.
Instead, I want the user to enter something like

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

All the input for the list will be on the same line, and the list will store each number as a item in the list, which will make the list like

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

is there a way to do that in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Comment: not really, I'm trying to find a way to store the items in the list as a int directly, every method out there will store it as a string

Answer (score 1):

Use the `split` function:

```
inpt = "1 2 3 4 5"
lst = inpt.split() -> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

if you want `int`:

```
lst = [int(i) for i in inpt.split()] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: so split will break a string directly into a list based on its spaces? And also is there a way to change it so that the numbers will be directly stored as an int instead of string?

Comment: Yes, split doesn't provide a type conversion but you can do a simple list comprehension. Check the updated code

Comment: okey ty! that really helped

Comment: You're welcome, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @rv.kvetch `input` is only there to sinalize the user input... not the actual variable.

Comment: you are assigning it using the `=`, so it looks like a variable to me

Comment: `input.split()` also certainly looks like a variable is being used to me - unless this is all actually just pseudo code, in which case I might have been reading it wrong.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, looks better overall to me at least.