# Python unit testing code which calls OS/Module level python functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, python-unittest

I have a python module/script which does a few of these

1. At various nested levels inside the script I take command line inputs, validate them, apply sensible defaults
2. I also check if a few directories exist

The above are just two examples. I am trying to find out what is the best "strategy" to test this. What I have done is that I have constructed wrapper functions around `raw_input` and `os.path.exists` in my module and then in my test I override these two functions to take input from my array list or do some *mocked* behaviour. This approach has the following disadvantages

1. Wrapper functions just exist for the sake of testing and this pollutes the code
2. I have to remember to use the wrapper function in the code everytime and not just call `os.path.exists` or `raw_input`

Any brilliant suggestions?

Comment: I added some more tags so this question gets more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) these system calls.

There are some good examples in the answer to [How to display the redirected stdin in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812333/how-to-display-the-redirected-stdin-in-python)

Here is a simple example for `raw_input()` using a `lambda` that throws away the prompt and returns what we want.

### System Under Test

```
$ cat ./name_getter.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

class NameGetter(object):

    def get_name(self):
        self.name = raw_input('What is your name? ')

    def greet(self):
        print 'Hello, ', self.name, '!'

    def run(self):
        self.get_name()
        self.greet()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ng = NameGetter()
    ng.run()

$ echo Derek | ./name_getter.py 
What is your name? Hello,  Derek !
```

### Test case:

```
$ cat ./t_name_getter.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
import name_getter

class TestNameGetter(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_alice(self):
        name_getter.raw_input = lambda _: 'Alice'
        ng = name_getter.NameGetter()
        ng.get_name()
        self.assertEquals(ng.name, 'Alice')

    def test_get_bob(self):
        name_getter.raw_input = lambda _: 'Bob'
        ng = name_getter.NameGetter()
        ng.get_name()
        self.assertEquals(ng.name, 'Bob')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

$ ./t_name_getter.py -v
test_get_alice (__main__.TestNameGetter) ... ok
test_get_bob (__main__.TestNameGetter) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution1: I would do something like this beacuse it works:

```
def setUp(self):
    self._os_path_exists = os.path.exists
    os.path.exists = self.myTestExists # mock

def tearDown(self):
    os.path.exists = self._os_path_exists
```

It is not so nice.

Solution2: Restructuring your code was not an option as you said, right?
It would make it worse to understand and unintuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Johnnysweb is spot on with what you need to do, but instead of rolling your own, you can import and use [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock).  Mock is specifically designed for unit testing, and makes it extremely simple to do what you're trying to do.  It's built-in to Python 3.3.

For example, if want to run a unit test that replaces os.path.isfile and always returns True:

```
try:
    from unittest.mock import patch
except ImportError:
    from mock import patch

class SomeTest(TestCase):

    def test_blah():
        with patch("os.path.isfile", lambda x: True):
            self.assertTrue(some_function("input"))
```

This can save you a LOT of boilerplate code, and it's quite readable.

If you need something a bit more complex, for example, replacing supbroccess.check_output, you can create a simple helper function:

```
def _my_monkeypatch_function(li):
     x,y = li[0], li[1]
     if x == "Reavers":
        return "Gorram"
     if x == "Inora":
        return "Shiny!"
     if x == y:
        return "The Ballad of Jayne"

def test_monkey():
     with patch("subprocess.check_output", _my_monkeypatch_function):
            assertEquals(subprocess.check_output(["Mudder","Mudder"]),
                                                 "The Ballad of Jayne")
```