# python, string comparison not working?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, compare

I have been tasked with creating a binary search over a list of words, I have come up with 2 implementations (and clearly haven't put in a case where the word isn't found yet but that's not an issue yet), however when the list is narrowed down to the word I am looking for, my function does not finish, instead it keeps running until maximum recursive depth is exceeded.

I put in print and it clearly shows the word at `dasList[mid]`, and shows this over and over again until it finally gives up.

```
def _bisect2(dasList, word):
    mid = int(len(dasList)/2)
    if word.lower() > dasList[mid].lower():
        return _bisect2(dasList[mid: len(dasList)], word)            
    if word.lower() < dasList[mid].lower():
        return _bisect2(dasList[0: mid], word)
    else:
        return mid
```

this is being called by

```
print(_bisect2(fileList, input('Please type a word')))
```

I am using the Python 3.0 interpretor. Any suggestions?

Comment: this error occurs for both implementations.

Comment: Just curious, did you forget to pre-sort `fileList`?

Comment: The standard library already includes a `bisect` module. Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation (almost) works for me (and doesn't show the behavior you described with my pre-sorted input).  I assume you've sorted your input files?  A slightly modified (working) example is posted below.

```
def _bisect2(dasList, word,lidx=0):
    mid = int(len(dasList)/2)
    if word.lower() > dasList[mid].lower():
        return _bisect2(dasList[mid:], word,lidx=lidx+mid)            
    elif word.lower() < dasList[mid].lower():
        return _bisect2(dasList[:mid], word,lidx=lidx)
    return lidx+mid

words=sorted(["one","two","three","four","five","twenty","foo"])
print (words)
print (_bisect2(words,'three'))
```

Note that you were returning the index in the last partial list (which will always be 0)...

Comment: yes the list of words is already sorted, and yes you're right it would return a 0. What i did notice however is the word i input seems to append a space onto the end. why would that be?

Comment: Well, that'll do it ;)  Then your word isn't in the list.  Just `strip` your input and you should be OK.

Comment: cool thanks. ^^ why would it append it? is it just the newline character being added after enter is pressed?

Comment: @Tony -- I'm not sure.  try using `raw_input` instead of `input` -- since you want strings, that's probably safer anyway.

Comment: @Tony The blank space at the end of your input you prompt for is odd and I can't reproduce that behavior with v 3.2.3

Comment: by all accounts 'raw_input()' has been changed to input
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3-1 
and after investigating '.strip()' I ran into '.rstrip()' which did the job as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tony -- Right, forgot you were using python 3.  Sorry about that ;).

Comment: @Levon yes it is confusing me a bit as well, and I can't see where or why it is happening. I might consider getting v3.2.3 after this debaccle

Comment: @mgilson all good, you atleast pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. Note that the index returned at the end will always be the index of the word in the minimal list, not the index of the original list.

See also that the `>` compare doesn't do a len over the list again, it just iterates to the end. Slice syntax allows you to leave off the last number if you're iterating to the end.

```
words = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".split()

def bisect(words, word):
    mid = int(len(words)/2)
    if word.lower() > words[mid].lower():
        return bisect(words[mid:], word)
    elif word.lower() < words[mid].lower():
        return bisect(words[0:mid], word)
    return mid

words = sorted(words)
print bisect(words, 'dog')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Python's [bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) module?

[Recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists) from the docs:

```
def index(a, x):
    'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    i = bisect_left(a, x)
    if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
        return i
    raise ValueError
```

Example:

```
>>> a = ['alfred','edward','mary','susan','thomas','wilma']
>>> index(a, 'mary')
2
>>> index(a, 'martha')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in index
ValueError
```

Comment: because it's more fun to figure out implementations ^^

Comment: @Tony:  Fair enough.  If speed is critical, use the bisect module.