# Matching inputs with a regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, input, match

I have a program that expects an input saying "yes", something like:

```
my_input = raw_input('> ')
if my_input == 'yes':
    #etc
```

But that's too specific, I want the input to match this regex: `[yY](es)?`, so that if the user puts "yes, Yes, y or Y", it is the same. But I don't know how is this implemented in python.

I want something like:

```
regex = some.regex.method('[yY](es)?')
my_input = raw_input('> ')
if my_input == regex:
    #etc
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regex is probably overkill here, but here is one way to do it:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'y(es)?$', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
my_input = raw_input('> ')
if regex.match(my_input):
    #etc
```

This will match the strings `"y"` or `"yes"` with any case, but will fail for a string like `"yellow"` or `"yesterday"`.

Or better yet, the same behavior without regex:

```
my_input = raw_input('> ')
if my_input.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
    #etc
```

---

Note: in Python 3 `raw_input` has been [replaced by `input`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954840/1080564).

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm staying with the tuple way.