# Python- raw_input not working

Tags: python, defined

Ok so I changed it to:

```
if input('a'):
      print ("You: Gimme a gun!")

if input('b'):
       print ("You: Fine")
```

But now I don't get a choice it forces me to choose a and then after that it forces me to choose b, once  I get past this hurdle I have the rest of the game in the bag but I really need help to figure this out
P.S. I am noob to python

```
import time
Gimme=True
Fine=True




print ("James: Ah, it looks like subject 091-266 is awake")
time.sleep(4)
print ("Scarlet: Hello, do you remember anything? The crash or anything?")
time.sleep(4)
print ("You: What.... Where am I?")
time.sleep(3)
print ("Scarlet: Oh, where are my manners, this is the head quarters of the XionRepublic, Xion")                        
time.sleep(5)
print ("James: You were involved in Z-9102, code named Attack-Z")
time.sleep(4)
print ("Scarlet: We were able to pull you and three others out before we  were forced to...")                                             
print ("James: Exterminate Alpha Base 12.")
time.sleep(6)
print ("You: Exterminate?! Couldn't you just quarantine it?")
time.sleep(4)
print ("Scarlet: No, Alpha Base 12 had over 3,000 people in it, it was to risky to quarantine")      
time.sleep(5)
print ("James: Do you recognize these names, Noah, Alex or Robert?")
time.sleep(4)
print ("You: Yes Alex!? Why? Is he ok?!")
time.sleep(3)
print ("James: Yes, Yes he was one of the three.")
time.sleep(4)
print ("*ALARM! SECURITY BREACHED, SECURITY BREACHED*")
time.sleep(4)
print ("James: Scarlet lock the door!")
time.sleep(3)
print ("You: Whats going on?!")
time.sleep(3)
print ("James: Z's there here.")
time.sleep(3)
print ("*Screaming*")
time.sleep(2)
print ("You: I can fight!")
time.sleep(3)
print ("Scarlet: Trust me you are not in any condition to fight due to some of the drugs in you")   
print ("CHOICE")
print ("A.Gimme the gun!")
print ("B.Fine")

if raw_input() == Gimme:
    print ("You: Gimme a gun!")
if raw_input() == Fine:
    print ("You: Fine")
```

Comment: If your python version is 3.x then use `input()`. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use raw\_input in Python 3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3-1)

Comment: Its not a duplicate, that does not even show up under related...

Comment: @user2278741: did you read the linked question?  It explains exactly what the problem is, and gives the same answer as the people who answered here to your original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the new versions of python -- 3.x.x -- then raw_input no longer exists. Use input(prompt) instead. It works pretty much the same. basic Syntax:

```
foo = input("some prompt").
```

What input does is it reads a line from the standard input file, or `<stdin>`. It prints the prompt within the `()` and then waits for user input. Example: (`>>>` is the command line prompt, `<<<` is output

```
Command Line, interactive mode (or IDLE): 
>>> foo = input("GIMME SOME INPUT: ")  #tell it to take some input
<<<GIMME SOME INPUT: foo          # it prints out, "GIMME SOME INPUT:" user types in foo
>>> print(foo)
<<< foo
```

Response to your edit:

Use this:

```
print ("CHOICE")
print ("A.Gimme the gun!")
print ("B.Fine")
choice = input("What do you choose?")
if choice == 'A' or choice == 'a':
    #Some Action 
if choice == 'B' or choice == 'b': 
    #Some Other Action
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using Python 3. In Python 3, [`raw_input()` has been renamed to `input()`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/).

Answer (score 1):

Re your new question:

> But now I don't get a choice it forces me to choose a and then after that it forces me to choose b

That's because you're calling `input()` twice, and each time you *call it*, you're prompted to type something.  You want to call it *once*, store the value you get in a variable, and compare that variable to the possible choices.

Comment: what are you reading to learn Python?  it should hopefully have explained variables by now...

Comment: When you call `input` function you are telling python that you want the user to make an input. If you call `input` twice, python will think you want two inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3 or later, then the `raw_input` function is replaced by normal `input()`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).