# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Code :

```
    n,X=input(),0
    for t in range(int(n)):
        eval(input())
    print(X)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 3, in <module>
    eval(input())
  File "<string>", line 1
    X++
      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Using `raw_input` instead of `input()` in the only solution I am able to find but in python 3.x `input` is `raw_input()`: [How do I use raw_input in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3-1)

any other method?

FYI; I am trying to solve: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/282/A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Remove* the `eval()` call.

`input()` in Python 2 is the equivalent of `eval(input())` in Python 3, and if you need to use `raw_input()` in Python 2 then in Python 3 you need to remove the `eval()` call.

You'll have to parse the input yourself; `++` is not a valid Python operator, you cannot use `eval()` to solve that Codeforces problem.

The simplest way to solve the posted problem is to read the input line by line:

```
import sys, itertools

count = int(next(sys.stdin))
x = 0
for line in itertools.islice(sys.stdin, count):
    x += 1 if '++' in line else -1
print(x)
```

Comment: 1/2 solution. first try to figure out what he wants to do.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Solve the linked coding puzzle, which involves parsing input with `X++`, `++X`, `X--` and `--X` inputs.

Comment: X++ is not a valid Python expression is good enough . i can handle it now thanx :) .