# Python - Not executing function

Tags: python-3.x

def Loans(x):
     x = int(raw_input("What is your FICO score? "))

if x >= 760:
        print ("Rate = 3.080")

elif x >= 700:
       print ("Rate = 3.302")

elif x >= 680:
       print ("Rate = 3.479")

elif x >= 660:
       print ("Rate = 3.693")

elif x >= 640:
       print ("Rate = 4.123")

elif x >= 620:
       print ("Rate = 4.66")

else:
       print ('Approval = No')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should be with the `raw_input` function. Try this:

```
def Loans(x):
    x = int(input("What is your FICO score? "))
    if x >= 760:
           print ("Rate = 3.080")
    elif x >= 700:
           print ("Rate = 3.302")
    elif x >= 680:
           print ("Rate = 3.479")
    elif x >= 660:
           print ("Rate = 3.693")
    elif x >= 640:
           print ("Rate = 4.123")
    elif x >= 620:
           print ("Rate = 4.66")
    else:
           print ('Approval = No')

Loans(10)
```

More details about the function renaming: https://stackoverflow.com/a/954840/2741329