# Python: Unable to stop this program's sentinel loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

SO I'm making a program about hockey players playing and I will record their goals.

Here's what should happen:

```
Who scored? 4
Who scored? 5
Who scored? 6
Who scored? 4
Who scored? 3
Game still going?(y/n) y
Who scored? 3
Who scored? 2
Who scored? 5
Who scored? 2
Who scored? 3
Game still going?(y/n) n

Creating a histogram from values: 
Element Goals Histogram
      1     0 
      2     2 **
      3     2 ***
      4     2 **
      5     2 **
      6     1 *
      7     1 *
      8     0 
      9     0 
     10     0
```

Here is my code:

```
def info():
    ranking = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    survey = []
    return ranking,survey
def info2(survey):   
    x = ''
    for i in range(0,5):
        x = int(input("Who scored?"))           
        survey.append(x)
    again(x)
    return survey
def info3(ranking,survey):
    for i in range(len(survey)):
        ranking[survey[i]]+=1
    return ranking, survey

def again(x):
    y = input("Game still on? y/n").lower()
    if y == "yes" or y == "y":
        info()
    elif y == "n" or y =="no":
        hg(x)


#create histogram
def hg():
    print("\nCreating a histogram from values: ")
    print("%3s %5s %7s"%("Element", "Goals", "Histogram"))

#start from element 1 instead of 0
    for i in range(len(ranking)-1):
        print("%7d %5d %-s"%(i+1, ranking[i+1], "*" * ranking[i+1]))

def main():
    x,y = info()
    a = info2(y)
    d = again(x)
    b,c = info3(x,a)
    z = hg(x)
main()
```

When I run this as it is, I get the Who scored thing, and I enter 'y' on the y/n and it works, but when I enter y/n and i put `n`, it prints the "element goals histogram" then throws the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 48, in <module>
    main()
 line 44, in main
    a = info2(y)
 line 17, in info2
    again(x)
 line 29, in again
    hg(x)
 line 39, in hg
    for i in range(len(ranking)-1):
NameError: name 'ranking' is not defined
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `x`?

Comment: printing it after `survey.append(x)` shows that it is not a list like i want it to be. :s

Comment: I think `input` is not the function you want. When writing a program it's helpful to test small parts of it, to make sure they work correctly, before putting it all together. For example, try `x = int(input("Who scored?"))` by itself.

Comment: So what should I put instead? @Lack

Comment: Oh my mistake, I just noticed the [python-3.x] tag. If it works as you want by itself, keep it in.

Comment: This is a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3-1

Comment: are you sure this is your code as you are running it?  looks like it will throw an error when you enter 'n' because your `hg` function takes one input, but you're calling it like `hg()` from the `again` function.

Comment: @zehnpaard i update the code... see what happens

Comment: This part `"1234567890".split()` is completely not necessary. You just converting it to a list in there.

Comment: You should change every use of 'x' and 'y' to descriptive variable names. Also change your function names. Naming things is really important to readable code.

Comment: true. but is that essential now or can i proceed still? @HåkenLid

Comment: If you can't read the code, you can't find the bugs.

Comment: i'll try to fix that and update code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues that I see with the code...

First, you've got `lower` instead of `lower()` in your `again()` function. This binds the function itself to `x` instead of calling it and assigning its return value.

Also, your `hg()` function expects an argument, but you don't pass one in here. The `ranking` defined in `info()` is local to that function, and not visible from `hg()`.

**Edit in response to OP after OP's code was updated based on my comments above:**

Also, there are issues with your handling of the exit case in `again()`. I think you shouldn't call `hg()` at all there, and instead return the answer to a separate variable in `info2()`.

So that code for those two functions would then look something like this:

```
def info2(survey):
    x = ''
    ans = 'y'

    while ans in ('y', 'yes'):
        for i in range(0,5):
            x = int(input("Who scored?"))
            survey.append(x)
        ans = again()
    return survey

def again():
    x = input("Game still on? y/n").lower()
    if x == "yes" or x == "y":
        info()

    return x
```

Note the use of the additional variable, and the `pass`.

**Edit in response to 2nd comment from OP:**

`info3()` is unchanged. I added  `again()` and `info2()` with my changes. You would keep `info3()` as is (at least as regards this particular question).

Also, since my change just had `pass` in the *No* case, it can actually be removed entirely. Just check for the *Yes* case, and otherwise return (an `else` isn't even required in this particular case).

When I run the code with the changes I mentioned, it appears to work as required. This is example output:

```
Who scored?1
Who scored?1
Who scored?1
Who scored?2
Who scored?2
Game still on? y/ny
Who scored?3
Who scored?3
Who scored?3
Who scored?2
Who scored?2
Game still on? y/nn

Creating a histogram from values: 
Element Goals Histogram
      1     3 ***
      2     4 ****
      3     3 ***
      4     0 
      5     0 
      6     0 
      7     0 
      8     0 
      9     0 
     10     0
```

Comment: info3() is not needed anymore?

Answer (score 2):

```
x = input("Game still on? y/n").lower
```

instead should be:

```
x = input("Game still on? y/n").lower()
```

Comment: Voted me down for that? I was still typing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what all of the functions and variables were supposed to do. It's easier to debug and understand code if you use sensible names for functions and variables.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def main():
    list_of_players = [str(number) for number in range(1, 11)]
    ranking = play(list_of_players)
    print_histogram(ranking)

def play(list_of_players):
    ranking = OrderedDict([(player, 0) for player in list_of_players])
    while True:
        for i in range(5):
            player = input('Who scored? ')
            try:
                ranking[player] += 1
            except KeyError:
                print('Not a player')
        if input('Game still going?(y/n) ').lower() in ['n', 'no']:
            return ranking

def print_histogram(ranking):
    template = '{player:^7} {goals:^7} {stars}'
    print('\nCreating a histogram from values: ')
    print(template.format(player='Element', goals='Goals', stars='Histogram'))
    for player, goals in ranking.items():
        print(template.format(player=player, goals=goals, stars='*' * goals))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: it gives name error when I select `y` if Game still going