# Request input from django custom command?

Tags: python, django

I've made a custom command in django to delete a set account in CMD, but I want to be able to run the python file and have the command line ask me for the account number to delete then have it delete. This is what I have so far.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from accounts.models import client

class Command(BaseCommand):

    args = '<client_id client_id ...>'
    help = 'Closes the specified account.'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for client_id in args:
            try:
                x = client.objects.get(pk=int(client_id))
            except client.DoesNotExist:
                raise CommandError('Client "%s" does no exist' % client_id)

            x.delete()

            self.stdout.write('Successfully closed account "%s"' % client_id)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the built-in [raw_input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    if args:
        ids = args
    else:
        ids = raw_input('Enter comma-delimited list of ids: ').split(',')
    for client_id in ids:
        ...
```

Edit: In Python3, use [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) instead of raw_input()

Comment: `input()` in Python 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3

Comment: NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined