# Why wont raw_input work when the file runs?

Tags: python

I am having problems with my game. I use the console to play. But I'm not sure why my console shows this:

```
File "/Volumes/AIDAN'S USB/MyGameFromScratch/assets/items.py", line 4
    original = raw_input(‘What is your name?’)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: this helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3-1

Comment: @neiesc that's not the problem. Check my answer. BTW, the error character shown by python is pointing the quotation mark, not saying that the function does not exist.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde you're right, I thought quickly.

Answer (score 4):

You are adding different quotation marks:

Yours:

```
original = raw_input(‘What is your name?’)
```

Mine:

```
original = raw_input('What is your name?')
```

Do you notice?

By the way, `raw_input` no longer works in Python 3. It is now `input`