# Debug at Python Compiler at file optr_assigment.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I see that error when i want to debug my python file:

```
C:\py>python optr_assigment.py<br>
**Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "optr_assigment.py", line 43, in <module><br>
    aplikasi = DemoOperator()<br>
  File "optr_assigment.py", line 8, in __in<br>
    x = raw_input("Masukkan nilai x: ")<br>
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined**
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3 changed `raw_input` to `input`.

[How do I use raw_input in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3-1)

Comment: thanks alexce and Dan Lowe :) for solved my problem