# What is wrong with this python code? If and else statements

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime

time_enter = datetime.now()
print ("Has a car entered the section?")
if raw_input() == "yes":
    print (datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"))
    datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
    time_leave= datetime.now()
    print ("Has a car leaved the section?")
    if raw_input() == "yes":
        print (datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        time_taken_to_travel = time_leave - time_enter
        print (time_taken_to_travel)
    else:
        print ("No car has leaved!")

else:
    print ("No car has entered!")
    print ("No car has leaved!")
```

Hello, I have edited my code as said below, but it says that there is some kind of an error with the line 5, and the raw input. Can you help to correct it?

```
Has a car entered the section?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\code.py", line 5, in <module>
    if raw_input() == "yes":
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

Comment: Does it at least tell you where the syntax error is? Perhaps the indentation 6-7 lines from the bottom?

Comment: Your `print (` lines are not closed with `)`.

Comment: you should close all the print function `i.e.)print (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))`

Comment: Please avoid those types of questions, SO is not a service for fixing code.

Comment: @Fabio - I disagree, something like 90-95% of the questions are for fixing errors in code. This question is just unclear

Comment: It does not tell me where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Without being too harsh, I must say your code looks like one big spaghetti mess. New lines, separating logic into functions and so on would easily give a better overview of the code.

On initial sight, this part of the code is at least wrong. When you define an `else` statement, it needs to have an indented block to execute.

```
 else:
 print("No car has leaved!")
 time_taken_to_travel = time_leave - time_enter
 print (time_taken_to_travel)
```

Should be something similar to this, or what you are trying to do :)

```
 else:
     print("No car has leaved!")

 time_taken_to_travel = time_leave - time_enter
 print (time_taken_to_travel)
```

EDIT:

OK, off the top, fixed the code to run in Python 2.7, take care of the different use of `print` if you run in Python > 3.

First off, when writing Python, the indentation is super important. Distinguish between 4 spaces and indentations. Your code was indented a space too much. You do not need to call `datetime.datetime.now`, just `datetime.now`. Secondly, why convert the dates to string when you subtract em? Keep them as dates and for input, `intput` is not the best solution. It will validate the inputted string. Use `raw_input` instead.

```
from datetime import datetime

time_enter = datetime.now()
print "Has a car entered the section?"
if raw_input() == "yes":
    print datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
    datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
    time_leave= datetime.now()
    print "Has a car leaved the section?"
    if raw_input() == "yes":
        print datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    else:
        print "No car has leaved!"
        time_taken_to_travel = time_leave - time_enter
        print time_taken_to_travel
else:
    print "No car has entered!"
    print "No car has leaved!"
```

With the output:

```
Has a car entered the section?
yes
11:41:54.281000
Has a car leaved the section?
yes
2015-10-15 11:41:55
```

Comment: Thats just one of the issues.

Comment: I edited it, but it came up with a raw input error :)

Comment: raw_input was renamed input in Python 3.x when i looked it up, so change it to input :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3-1