# How to multiply fractions passed down as a tuple

Tags: python

```
def mult(num):
    #num='(1,2)(3,4)'
    numn=int(num[1])
    denom=int(num[3])
    numn1=int(num[6])
    denom1=int(num[8])
    numnetor=numn*numn1
    denominetor=denom * denom1
    ans=str(numnetor)+'/'+ str(denominetor)
    return ans
askUser=input("Enter Fraction:")
print(mult(askUser))
```

I tried to do it this way but when I input double digit number it crashes What can I do?

Comment: A string of a tuple, are you sure you need to play with fire like that?

Comment: You say they're "passed down as a tuple", but they aren't, they're passed in as a string. That means `num[1]` isn't taking a number from tuple, it's taking the second character from the string. (And if it was being passed in as a list of tuples, it wouldn't work because num[1] would be the second tuple and num[3/6/8] would error).

Comment: How can i change my code to do that to input two tuple like this (12,10)(40,2) and then multiply them.@ TessellatingHeckler

Comment: Is there something wrong with using the `fractions` module as i did in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressing my doubt that you will actually need to process strings of compound tuples, the solution you are looking for is `raw_input` (instead of `input`), and `ast` (which is what `input` does).

Now, when the two tuples are understood separately, the program may now process numbers with more than two digits.

```
import ast

def mult(num):
    sep_indx = num.find(')(')
    assert sep_indx > -1

    tuple1, tuple2 = num[:sep_indx+1], num[sep_indx+1:]
    tuple1 = ast.literal_eval(tuple1)
    tuple2 = ast.literal_eval(tuple2)

    numn=int(tuple1[0])
    denom=int(tuple1[1])
    numn1=int(tuple2[0])
    denom1=int(tuple2[1])
    numnetor=numn*numn1
    denominetor=denom * denom1
    ans=str(numnetor)+'/'+ str(denominetor)
    return ans

askUser=raw_input("Enter Fraction:")
print(mult(askUser))

#Enter Fraction:(1,20)(3,40)
#3/800
```

Do note that your program will still have problems with division by zero errors, issue with extra spaces, and any non-integer numbers entered by the user. I am leaving these to you.

Comment: The OP could be using Python 3. Also, what is the advantage of this over the `fractions` module?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with using fractions for normal problems. I am just answering the question.

Comment: Wow @ppperry [this is ridiculous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/954840/1558430), thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Python already has support for fractions in the standard library.
If your fraction is in string form:

```
from fractions import Fraction
f = Fraction(askUser)
```

If your fraction is in tuple form:

```
f = Fraction(*fraction_tuple)
```

The resulting `Fraction` objects can be used in standard arithmetic as if they were numbers.

Comment: i didn't understand your answer @pperry

Comment: What's ambiguous about it? @EzanaTesfaye, you don't need to say `@ppperry` when talking in the comments on my answer, as it automatically notifies me.

Comment: oh ok The answer you gave divides it the thing i wanted to do is 
ask the user for an input like this  (10,2)(12,4) and multiply the two fractions-> 10/2 * 12/4=120/8