# Cannot find error in Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting an error when trying to run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\healthtest.py", line 3, in <module>
    if raw_input() == "Hit":
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

I do not know what I did wrong, but here is the code I have been using.

```
health = "10"

    if raw_input() == "Hit":
    health = health - 5
```

I hope you can help me, and thanks in advance.

Comment: [**`raw_input`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) is Python 2.7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use raw\_input in Python 3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **`raw_input()`** and not **`raw_input`**

Unless you are using Python 3.x, where it has been renamed to **input()**

Also, regarding **health**, you are first assigning it a string value and then trying to take away -5 as if it's an int().

Comment: I fixed that. I just uploaded a old version of code. Let me edit that.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Andrew You didn't fix it! There is NO `raw_input` in Python 3.x

Comment: Thanks so much! That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#input) and indenting properly

```
health = 10 # health is an integer not a string

if input()=='hit':
    health -= 5 # pay attention to the indentation


hit # my input

health
Out[34]: 5 # output of health after input
```

You can take this further my assigning `input()` to a var to do more validation.

```
inp = input()

if inp.lower()=='hit':
    # continue code
```

The [`.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.lower) allows input such as 'hit', 'Hit', 'HIT'...

```
'Hit' == 'hit'
Out[35]: False

'Hit'.lower() == 'hit'
Out[36]: True
```

Comment: Thanks :D This is also very helpful!