# Python while loop to prompt until stop is entered

Tags: python

I need the code to ask the user to enter a word and print them out in a sentence once stop is entered. I have the following code:

```
`a = input("Enter a word: ")
 sentence = () 
 while a != ("stop"):
 sentence = sentence , a
 a = input("Enter a word: ")
 print (sentence)`
```

However I don't know how to set the variable 'Sentence' so that nothing prints at the start. How can I rectify this?

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what you would like to do?

Comment: I want the program to prompt the user to enter words until the word "stop" is entered. As the words are entered they should be added to the variable 'sentence'. When the loop finishes due the word "stop" being entered, the variable 'sentence' should be printed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
a = input("Enter a word: ")
sentence = "" 
while a != "stop":
    sentence = sentence + " " + a
    a = input("Enter a word: ")
print (sentence)
```

`input` (`raw_input` in python 2) will allow you to write strings without the need for quotes. Sentence has to be initialized to an empty string `""`, and concatenated as a string (here with a simple `+` ).

Comment: If the initial space bothers you, you can use `print (sentence[1:])` to skip it.

Comment: 'raw_input' is not defined in my version of python. I am using python 3.3.2.

Comment: I have used 'input' instead of 'raw_input' and it has worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: True, there is an answer for that here [raw_input python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3-1)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a string, you need to use raw_input() instead input() (input saves as int, double etc...).

Replace input() to raw_input().

In addition, sentence = () - saves tuple and sentence = sentence , a - adds more tuples and not a string as i think you want.

Try to explain again what you mean.

Comment: I want the program to prompt the user to enter words until the word "stop" is entered. As the words are entered they should be added to the variable 'sentence'. When the loop finishes due the word "stop" being entered, the variable 'sentence' should be printed.

Comment: Yes I do want a string and not a tuple. How can I do this?

Comment: Do sentence = "" and sentence += a.