# Processing 3 Python Mode: Can't Type to console

Tags: python, input, console, processing

I have just recently been getting into programming and I am in the middle of a real basic python project. I'm using Processing 3 and for the life of me I can't figure out how to type to the console.

My input code is this:

```
encode("%s"%(raw_input("Type Message:")), 2)
```

The "type message here:" prompt appears but I can't seem to click on it or be able to "use" it for input.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3-1 meaning `raw_input = input` .Please use google before asking a questions.

Comment: Are you using the Processing editor?