# Python try -except in raw_input()

Tags: python

What is wrong with the following code? I get an error.

```
largest = 0
smallest = 0

while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

    try:
        num = int(num)
        if num == 'done':
            break 
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue

    if num < smallest:
        smallest = num

    if num > largest:
        largest = num

print('Maximum is ', largest)
print('Minimum is ', smallest)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Whenever I'm trying to take string as input its showing 'NamEerror'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But still get an error .  http://ideone.com/nNJ0DZ

Comment: Please include the error message in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, please include your error messages in the question.  This is your error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 5, in <module>
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

That's because [in Python 3 `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954840/120999).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run a Python 2 application with a Python 3 interpreter.