# TypeError while running argv Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '> '

print ("Hi %s, I'm the %s script.") % (user_name, script)
print ("I'd like to ask you a few questions.")
print ("Do you like me %s?") % user_name
likes = raw_input(prompt)

print ("Where do you live %s?") % (user_name)
lives = raw_input(prompt)

print ("What kind of computer do you have?")
computer = raw_input(prompt)

print """
Alright, so you said %r about liking me.
You live in %r. Not sure where that is.
And you have a %r computer. Nice.
""" % (likes, lives, computer)
```

While running this (Python 3) code in PowerShell I am getting

> Type error 'unsupported operand type(s) for %:'Nonetype' and 'str''

What is the error here?

Comment: For the future: Please also post the full stack trace of the error you are seeing. Otherwise we just have to guess *where* the error occurs. If you look at it yourself, you could have seen that the error appears on the line of the `print` call, so it has nothing to do with `argv` or anything.

Comment: This code seems to be very broken. You are using python3? Yet dont use the print function (with parenthesis) and you do use `raw_input`. Are you sure its not py2?

Comment: @PaulRooney Once fixing the error from the question, OP will likely see a `NameError` for the `raw_input` use.

Comment: You're **not** running **this** script in Python 3. It throws `SyntaxError`. Please recheck that code in your question matches the code you're actually running and produces the *same problem*.

Answer (score 2):

```
print ("Hi %s, I'm the %s script.") % (user_name, script)
```

`print` is a function in Python 3, so this is doing something different to what you expect. The first set of parentheses belong to the `print` function call, so what you have is this:

```
print("Hi %s, I'm the %s script.")  %  (user_name, script)
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
# only that is the argument to the print call
```

So if you split this up in separate statements, it would look like this:

```
print_result = print("Hi %s, I'm the %s script.")
format_args = (user_name, script)

print_result % format_args
```

Now, calling `print()` returns nothing, i.e. `None`. So you are essentially doing the following:

```
None % format_args
```

And that causes the exact error you are seeing.

What you want to do instead is ensure that the string formatting happens for the *argument* passed to the `print` call, like so:

```
print("Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name, script))
```

Note that you do not need to put a string in additional parentheses. So there is only a single opening parenthesis for the `print` call which is closed at the very end.

---

As Paul Rooney pointed out in the comments, once you have fixed those `print` calls, you will likely run into a `NameError` for your use of `raw_input`. `raw_input` does not exist in Python 3, so you will need to fix that too. See also [this question on that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/954834/216074).