# How do I use raw_input to set a variable to any word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I've been working on a project recently to refresh on my Python, and I need to set a variable to a name. 
`name = raw_input("What is your name?")` Is what I have so far, and I can't get it to set the variable (name) to be any word. When I put `print (name)` in the line after, it comes up with an error. How do I set the variable to anything that the player inputs?

Comment: if you are using python 3, `input()` is all you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use raw\_input in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python version `3.x` then for raw_input() you will got error saying `NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined`. For python3.X you can use `name = input("What is your name?")`

while what you are doing will run in `python2.X` perfectly.