# Syntax error in python 3 when I'm trying to convert a date but no luck on trying to solve it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert date (i.e. 6/15/2000) to the day, month abbreviation, and year (i.e. 15 June, 2000) in python 3

```
def main():
    dateStr = raw_input("Enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy): ")
    monthStr, dayStr, yearStr = string.split(dateStr, "/")
    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    monthStr = months[int(monthStr)–1]   

main()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3

Comment: Which Python tutorial are you following? Which version of Python is that tutorial designed for? Does that match the version of Python you are using?

Comment: **Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it.** https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your `–` in `int(monthStr)–1` is not the minus sign but a _dash_, replace with a `-`. if you posted the error it would be easier to help. (Also `raw_input()` is not in Python 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Python 3 Code:**

```
def main():
    dateStr = input("Enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy): ")
    monthStr, dayStr, yearStr = dateStr.split("/")
    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    monthStr = months[int(monthStr)-1]
    print ('Converted Date: ' + ' '.join([str(dayStr), monthStr, str(yearStr)]))

main()
```

**Python 2 Code: Use `raw_input`:**

```
def main():
    dateStr = raw_input("Enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy): ")
    monthStr, dayStr, yearStr = dateStr.split("/")
    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    monthStr = months[int(monthStr)-1]
    print ('Converted Date: ' + ' '.join([str(dayStr), monthStr, str(yearStr)]))

main()
```

**Explanation**

First, your `split` syntax seems to be incorrect. it should be `<str>.split(<split character>)` i.e. `dateStr.split("/")`

Next, in Python 3, there is no `raw_input` as it is renamed as `input()`.

Lastly, I added the `print` statement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Posting code without explaining what problem you've solved is useless.

Comment: I have added explanation, thanks.