# User reading and writing to a file

Tags: python, file

i am trying to write a program that if a user press 1, it reads the file, if 2, it write to the file and if 3, it erase the file. Unfortunately, the code stop working after the first input from user. Is it possible to write a function for that?

```
while True:
    print("(1) Read the notebook")
    print("(2) Add note")
    print("(3) Empty the notebook")
    print("(4) Quit")

    user_input = input("Please select one: ")

    if user_input == 1:
        readfile = open("notebook.txt","r")
        content = readfile.read()
        print(content)
        readfile.close()

    elif user_input == 2:
        new_input = input("Write a new note: ")
        readfile = open("notebook.txt", "a")
        readfile.write(new_input)
        readfile.close()

    elif user_input == 3:
        readfile = open("notebook.txt", "w")
        readfile.close()

    elif user_input == 4:
        break

print("Notebook shutting down, thank you.")
```

Comment: "Unfortunately, the code doesn't work as i intend."  Why not? What's breaking?

Comment: In what way is it not working as intended?

Comment: in python 3, input returns a string not an integer

Comment: `input` always returns a string. You need to convert it to `int` or check for string values e.g. `if user_input == '1':`

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 The code did not execute the if part.

Comment: @JosephFarah The code is works such that when the user press 1, the code reads the file, when 2 is entered it write to the file and when 3 is entered it deletes the file while 4 exit the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python3 does not have separate `raw_input()` and `input()` functions for returning `int`s and `string`s. It only has `input()`, which returns a string. You are attempting to compare the output of `input()` (a `string`) to an `int`, for example on this line:

```
if user_input == 1:
```

The solution is to use the `int()` function to get the types right, i.e.

```
if int(user_input) == 1:
```

#### More reading

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3)

[Source 2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)

Comment: Thanks. I did use use int() earlier but the code didn't run at all. I will try that and see.

Comment: @superv could you please update your original question with what you mean by "not run at all"?

Comment: Thanks guys. I saw i did not add a line of code earlier on. i have done that and also add the int() conversion. The code seems to work but with few errors which i cant seems to find. here is the code:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your user input should be an int. Use this instead :=>"user_input = int(input("Please select one: "))"
And also you cannot write an integer to a file so use this: => "readfile.write("user_input")" or convert your user input to string before writing to the file.

Comment: Thanks. I did use use int() earlier but the code didn't run at all.

Comment: `readfile.write("user_input")` will not do what they want. That's not how to convert to string

Comment: @roganjosh is right, its just going to write the string "user_input" to the file.

Comment: it's just an example

Comment: I did ask him to convert to string before writing to file

Comment: @superv use this to get the exact value you want wrriten to the file:=> readfile.write(str(user_input))

Comment: @superv kindly mark as answered

Comment: I have fixed that part. Thanks Chinonso.

Comment: I have edited the code. Most part has worked as i expected but now am getting this error : Incorrect output: your program printed "3(1)", but should have printed "3Notes". What might the problem?

Comment: if you run your code with option 1 first you will get an error as you are trying to read a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: post your new code let me check

Comment: post your code let me check here

Comment: @ChinonsoNgwu I have solved it. Thanks man. Which side your come from naija?