# Python program giving error for raw_input()

Tags: python, input

Is there any way of getting string input from user, other than raw-input, as that generates an error in my python program?

```
choice = raw_input("Do you want to convert from celcius to farenheit?")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? raw_input was replaced by input when switching from Python 2 to 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` is not working because you are using Python 3. If you want raw_input, try downgrading to use Python 2 instead.

Alternatively, if you must use Python 3, you can use the function `input` like so:

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
```