# I downloaded this scrpit

Tags: python

```
  File "C:\Users\Dk\Desktop\New folder\DDos.py", line 18, in <module>
    host=raw_input(":" )
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

I get this error when I run this code:

```
print ("DDoS mode loaded")
print ("python script ")
host=raw_input(":" )
port=input(":" )
```

Comment: If you are using Python3 replace `raw_input()` with `input()`

Comment: Just be warned that if the script is in Python 2 there are probably many other things in it that are not compatible with Python 3. See if you Can find a more up-to date version. I can not recommend that you switch to using Python 2.  It has been obsolete for years and reached end-of-life a year ago, so it is no longer supported.

Comment: try installing python2 for it to work unchanged

Comment: I'd not trust that script especially if you cannot understand the code. Best to just delete it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use raw\_input in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1):

raw_input in Python 2.x is replaced by input in Python 3.x.

Try using **input** instead of **raw_input**.

If you regularly work with Python 2.x, you might want to look into the Python 2 and 3 compatiblity library named **six**. This will help you develop code that has lesser compatibility issues.
[Official docs for six](https://six.readthedocs.io/)