# How to call for an input value from widget in Google colab?

Tags: python, input, widget, google-colaboratory, eoferror

I want to define a widget button (named start in this case) that when I press it, starts to ask for an input from the user.
Here is the code I use:

```
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets

Start_button = widgets.Button(description="Start")
Start_output = widgets.Output()

display(Start_button, Start_output)

def Start_button_clicked(b):
with Start_output:
print("test Button clicked.")
test = input('input')

Start_button.on_click(Start_button_clicked)
```

But it gives me `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is it `python3` or `python2`? Does this conversation help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954834/how-do-i-use-raw-input-in-python-3

Comment: It's `python3` so I believe `input()` command is safe to use