# easiest way to pause a command-line python program?

Tags: python, command-line

Let's say I have a python program that is spitting out lines of text, such as:

```
while 1:
  print "This is a line"
```

What's the easiest way to allow one to press a key on the keyboard to pause the loop, then to resume if pressed again---but if nothing is pressed it should just continue on automatically?

I'm hoping I don't have to go into something like curses to get this!

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577467/pause-in-python???

Comment: @Preet Sangha: I wouldn't say this is a duplicate. The question here is how can you make the program pause when *the user* wants it to and what you are referring to is about making the program pause when *it* wants to.

Comment: Oh ok I stand corrected.

Comment: "What's the easiest way..." Always involves actually writing code to actually check the keyboard.  What have you tried?  Since checking the keyboard varies by OS, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this implementation for **Linux** / **Mac** (and possible other Unices) (code attribution: [found on ActiveState Code Recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572182-how-to-implement-kbhit-on-linux/)).

On **Windows** you should check out [msvcrt](http://effbot.org/librarybook/msvcrt.htm).

```
import sys, termios, atexit
from select import select

# save the terminal settings
fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
new_term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
old_term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

# new terminal setting unbuffered
new_term[3] = (new_term[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO)

# switch to normal terminal
def set_normal_term():
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, old_term)

# switch to unbuffered terminal
def set_curses_term():
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, new_term)

def putch(ch):
    sys.stdout.write(ch)

def getch():
    return sys.stdin.read(1)

def getche():
    ch = getch()
    putch(ch)
    return ch

def kbhit():
    dr,dw,de = select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
    return dr <> []
```

Implementing what you're looking for would then become something like this:

```
atexit.register(set_normal_term)
set_curses_term()

while True:
    print "myline"
    if kbhit():
        print "paused..."
        ch = getch()
        while True
            if kbhit():
                print "unpaused..."
                ch = getch()
                break
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for *me*, assuming I was working in bash, would be to hit Control-Z to suspend the job, then use the 'fg' command to restore it when I was ready. But since I don't know what platform you're using, I'll have to go with using ChristopheD's solution as your best starting point.

Answer (score 0):

When you press Ctrl+C, a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception gets raised in your program. You can catch that exception to create the behavior you want - for instance, to pause the program and resume after 5s:

```py
import time

while True:
     try:
         # This is where you're doing whatever you're doing
         print("This is a line")
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print("Paused! Ctrl+C again within 5 seconds to kill program")
         # A second KeyboardInterrupt that happens during this sleep will
         # not be caught, so it will terminate the program
         time.sleep(5)
         print("Continuing...")
```

Or to pause the program indefinitely until the user hits 'enter':

```py
while True:
     try:
         # This is where you're doing whatever you're doing
         print("This is a line")
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print("Interrupted!")
         input("Press enter to continue, or Ctrl+C to terminate.")
         print("Continuing...")
```

If you want to catch a second `KeyboardInterrupt` as well and do something fancy with that, you can do so by nesting `try/except` blocks, though I wouldn't really recommend that - it's a good idea to allow a string of `KeyboardInterrupt`s to terminate the program.